# Fixed horizontal ScrollView above ListFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I am displaying a list using a custom ListFragment.  The fragment inflates a layout and works fine. I want to add a horizontal scrollView above the fragment to act as a category menu.  It must be fixed, so addHeaderView is not acceptable.

I found a layout example here on SO and plugged it into my layout to see how it could be made to work.  But in its current form below, it does what you would expect - puts a horizontal scrollview in every entry on the list.

So how do I share a screen with a static view on top and the listfragment below.

Here is the layout that does not work - as I mentioned the Scrollview part is not mine and is only included as an example. The relativelayout at the bottom makes the actual list

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false" >
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hor_svID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:focusable="false" >
        <!--android:background="@drawable/submenu_bg"> -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/TechnologyTxtVId" 
                    android:text="TECHNOLOGY"   
                    android:textColor="#342D7E"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/SportsTxtVId" 
                    android:text="SPORTS" 
                    android:textColor="#342D7E" 
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:paddingLeft="15dip"></TextView> 
            <TextView android:id="@+id/EntntTxtVId" 
                    android:text="ENTERTAINMENT"    
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#342D7E"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/LocalTxtVId" 
                    android:text="LOCAL"    
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#342D7E"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>        
            <TextView android:id="@+id/WorldTxtVId" 
                    android:text="WORLD"    
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#342D7E"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>    
            <TextView android:id="@+id/FeaturesTxtVId" 
                    android:text="FEATURES" 
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#342D7E"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>        
            <TextView android:id="@+id/RecentTxtVId" 
                    android:text="RECENT"   
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#342D7E"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>                                
        </LinearLayout>                                     
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false" >

         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_source"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_thumbnail"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_pubDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewHeadline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_thumbnail"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView_pubDate"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewSummary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewHeadline"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_thumbnail"
            android:maxLines="@integer/Four"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />



    </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I see your horizontal scroll view but what's that second relative layout for? I'd expect to have the list view in that position, also your parent RelativeLayout should be changed to a LinearLayout as it only has 2 elements in it and they're on top of each other.

Comment: Why don't you add the ScrollView on top of your listFragment in your Activitiy's layout? (or use a listView inside a 'normal' Fragment and put the scrollView on top of it...)

Comment: Of course - I wasn't thinking.  It should be in teh activity not the fragment.  I use one Activity for all fragments, but will have to change that since this scroll view belongs in some but not others. Thanks.